# Filter Opacity not Working for Checkbox (IE8)

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-8, opacity

I did some customization on a `checkbox` and try to make the opacity working in IE8.
The `-ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=20)"`; is working on a div, but when I use checkbox, it's not working. In chrome and firefox, the opacity works correct. Opacity works for input/label elements?

**HTML:**

```
    <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4 data-stats">
       <div class="check-user-data">
          <input type="checkbox" value="checked" id="review-username" name="check"/>
          <label for="review-username"></label>
       </div>
    </div>
```

**CSS:**

```
input[type=checkbox] {
        visibility: hidden;
    }

    .check-user-data {
        height: 50px;
        text-align: center;
    }

    .check-user-data label {
        cursor: pointer;
        position: absolute;
    }

    .check-user-data label:after {
        font-family: 'Glyphicons Halflings';
        content: "\e013";
        position: absolute;

        /* IE 8 */
        -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=20)";

        opacity: 0.2;
    }

    .check-user-data label:hover::after {
        color: #49FF90;

        /* IE 8 */
        -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=50)";

        opacity: 0.5;
    }

    .check-user-data input[type=checkbox]:checked + label:after {
        color: #3BCC73;

        /* IE 8 */
        -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=100)";

        opacity: 1;
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you include all the relevant opacity properties:

```
/* IE 8 */
-ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=20)";

/* IE 5-7 */
filter: alpha(opacity=20);

/* Netscape Based Browsers (Mozilla */
-moz-opacity: 0.2;

/* For early Safari's (1.x) */
-khtml-opacity: 0.2;

/* Official CSS property */
opacity: 0.2;
```

I don't know which browser's you support but that should provide you support for most of the versions of the mainstream browsers in use today.

Also, I ran into this problem myself in some code. Make sure the checkbox in question does not have a `z-index` above the parent that has the opacity. I found that, contrary to the official specification, Chrome and Firefox will make all elements within a parent opaque if the parent is opaque. IE actually implements it correctly, where it not only takes into consideration the parent the element is in but also the z-index of the element in releation to the parent.

**Example 1:**

```
<!-- Markup -->
<div id="parent" class="transparent">
    <div id="child"></div>
</div>

/* CSS */
.transparent {
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=20)";
    filter: alpha(opacity=20);
    -moz-opacity: 0.2;
    -khtml-opacity: 0.2;
    opacity: 0.2;
}
```

In this case both the parent and child elements will have the opacity properties applied to them.

**Example 2:**

```
<!-- Markup -->
<div id="parent" class="transparent">
    <div id="child"></div>
</div>

/* CSS */
#parent {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 0;
}

#child {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
}

.transparent {
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=20)";
    filter: alpha(opacity=20);
    -moz-opacity: 0.2;
    -khtml-opacity: 0.2;
    opacity: 0.2;
}
```

In this example, the child element has a z-index larger than the parent. In essence, if you were able to rotate the markup 90 degrees around the x-axis, you would see two separate layer on the z-axis. In the above example, I've found that Chrome and Firefox render both elements opaque even though the elements reside on two different layers. In IE they do not (per the official specification). [Here](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-color/#transparency) is the official specification on the opacity property. Below is the relevant snippet:

> Since an element with opacity less than 1 is composited from a single offscreen image, content outside of it cannot be layered in z-order between pieces of content inside of it. For the same reason, implementations must create a new stacking context for any element with opacity less than 1. If an element with opacity less than 1 is not positioned, implementations must paint the layer it creates, within its parent stacking context, at the same stacking order that would be used if it were a positioned element with ‘z-index: 0’ and ‘opacity: 1’. If an element with opacity less than 1 is positioned, the ‘z-index’ property applies as described in [CSS21], except that ‘auto’ is treated as ‘0’ since a new stacking context is always created. See section 9.9 and Appendix E of [CSS21] for more information on stacking contexts. The rules in this paragraph do not apply to SVG elements, since SVG has its own rendering model ([SVG11], Chapter 3).

I know this may be a little more than you were looking for, but I saw you had positioning within your CSS and I've been bitten by this problem before so I thought I would share.

Best of luck and happy coding!